# Transformation Parameters from ETRS89 (2004) to WGS84

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84

I have XYZ coordinates of a point measured in year 2004 in ETRS89 coordinate system and I need to transform it to geodetic coordinates in WGS84.
Since ETRS89 changes yearly, so do the transformation parameters.
-As far as I understood there is about 2.5 cm change per year.

I am wondering where could those transformation parameters for the year 2004 be found in order to perform the needed transformation.

Comment: GIS tools usually do not make any difference between WGS84 and ETRS89. Difference is important in geodetic research. Are you doing such?

Comment: I am actually doing a research and will be off to a field work on the weekend and will have to set up a base station on that point. The WGS84 coordinates I need in order to input them in the base station.

Comment: You should actually be looking for transformations to ITRFxx as true WGS84 coordinates are only available to US military and allies. WGS 84 is now kept consistent with ITRF and the fit has been getting better over time. See [this page](https://confluence.qps.nl/display/KBE/Howto+Deal+with+ETRS89+Datum+and+Time-dependent+Transformation+Parameters) for some possible transformations.

Answer (score 1):

The official site http://etrs89.ensg.ign.fr/ mentions that after ETRF2000 it was decided to continue using that frame for 2005 and 2008. So your data should be in the ETRF2000 frame.

You may find more hints at [How can I convert/transform coordinates from ETRS89 to WGS84 UTM 36N in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66697/how-can-i-convert-transform-coordinates-from-etrs89-to-wgs84-utm-36n-in-qgis) and http://www.novatel.com/support/known-solutions/wgs84-to-etrs89-datum-transformations/